# How to do the right way to dectect whether the browser supports border-image?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, browser-feature-detection

I made a HTML app that use border-image.

Chrome always updates automatically, and FireFox support -moz-border-image since 3.5+. So I think it's safe to say that most Chrome and FireFox user can enjoy the effect. But for IE user, I also want them to enjoy a less enjoyable, but tolerable effect.

Therefore, I think I need a proper way to find whether the browser support border-image using JavaScript and do some hack, and I don't know how to do this.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh475813.aspx (Feature Detection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Modernizr, you can create your own custom download with just the features you need to detect. http://modernizr.com/download/